# Android refreshing TextView with checkbox onClick?

Tags: android, listview, textview

I'm trying to dynamically update (change color and strikethrough text) a TextView  within  a ListView when the user checks a CheckBox.

My code works somewhat but for some reason only on the second click of the checkbox i.e. user checks nothing happens, user un-checks and checks a second time TextView then updates as required?

Any help appreciated.

my code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.shoppinglist, parent, false);
    }

    String anItem = get_Item(position);//from item array

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSLItemName)).setText(anItem);

    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBoxSL);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            View aView = convertView;
            if (aView == null) {
                aView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.shoppinglist, parent, false);
            }
            if(isChecked){  

                checked[position] = true;
                ((TextView) aView.findViewById(R.id.tvSLItemName)).setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                ((TextView) aView.findViewById(R.id.tvSLItemName)).setPaintFlags(
                        ((TextView) aView.findViewById(R.id.tvSLItemName)).getPaintFlags()
                        | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                //aView.invalidate();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            else{
                checked[position] = false;
            }

        }
    });

    checkBox.setChecked(checked[position]);
    return view;
}
```

**Updated code as suggested below:**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.shoppinglist, parent, false);
    }

    String anItem = get_Item(position);//from item array

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSLItemName)).setText(anItem);

    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBoxSL);

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View aView = convertView;
            if (aView == null) {
                aView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.shoppinglist, parent, false);
            }
            if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                checked[position] = true;
                ((TextView) aView.findViewById(R.id.tvSLItemName)).setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                ((TextView) aView.findViewById(R.id.tvSLItemName)).setPaintFlags(
                        ((TextView) aView.findViewById(R.id.tvSLItemName)).getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                //aView.invalidate();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                checked[position] = false;
            }

        }
    });

    checkBox.setChecked(checked[position]);
    return view;
}
```

No change to problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it, not quite sure what was was going on, maybe someone can explain in detail? Anyhow,  the issue was with me declaring the TextView repeatedly within the getView(), simply declaring it as a variable (tv in this case) then calling tv within the method worked. Thanks for the help.

```
        @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.shoppinglist, parent, false);
        }
        final TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvSLItemName);
        String anItem = get_Item(position);//from item array
        tv.setText(anItem);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBoxSL);        
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                View aView = convertView;
                if (aView == null) {
                    aView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.shoppinglist, parent, false);
                }
                if(isChecked){                          
                    checked[position] = true;                       
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);                    
                    tv.setPaintFlags(
                            ((TextView) aView.findViewById(R.id.tvSLItemName)).getPaintFlags()
                            | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();     
                }
                else{
                    checked[position] = false;
                }                   
            }
        });         
        checkBox.setChecked(checked[position]);
        return view;
    }
```